# How to show only the top portion of an image with CSS?

Tags: css

If an image is taller than 115 px, I'd like to only show the top 115px in a square container.  I'm trying this with the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/3mRh9/

But I still see the whole image.  How can I always show only the top portion of an image using only CSS?

Code:

```
<div>
    <div class="floated"> 
        <a class="limited">
            <img src="http://change.gov/page/-/officialportrait.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>


.floated {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: left;
}
.limited {
    width: 115px;
    height: 115px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
img {
    max-width: 115px;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/3mRh9/1/

Add `display: block` to your `.limited` style.

```
.limited {
    width: 115px;
    height: 115px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: block;
}
```

`<a>` tags are inline by default, and inline elements cannot have width or height.

Alternatively, you could just wrap with a block-level element, like a `div`, instead ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3mRh9/3/)):

```
<div>
    <div class="floated"> 
        <div class="limited">
            <a href="http://example.com">
                <img src="http://change.gov/page/-/officialportrait.jpg"/>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1+ This time you were faster ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is a property that will allow this for showing only part of an image.

It's `clip` but it only works on absolutely positioned objects.

[**JSFiddle Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/L7cdK/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div class="floated"> 
        <a class="limited">
            <img src="http://change.gov/page/-/officialportrait.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.floated {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: left;
}
.limited {
    width: 115px;
    height: 115px;
    display:block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position:relative;
}

img {
    position:absolute;
    clip:rect(0px,115px,115px,0px);

}
```

*I'm not sure if this is the effect you are after but it is what you asked for.*